# I set a frequency too high for my monitor. How can I get it back to normal?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a Geforce 8500GT on my PC, and I made the stupid mistake of setting it to a higher frequency than my monitor can manage.
It boots up and it shows me this…

[image]

and that's all. I can't do anything.

The thing is that I think this video board is a little broken anyway, because when it boots up i can't see anything until Windows starts loading. But it worked fine after, no problems.

I'm on my on-board video board now, and I don't know how to set the frequency back, because when I boot up with the on-board one, it says something like "changing freq" and it goes ok.

How can I get the frequency back for the 8500Gt?

Comment: What happens when you boot into safe mode and change the resolution?

Comment: Well, before I did the dumb thing of changing the freq, I couldn't see anything until Windows 7 started loading. And now, I can't see anything until this error pops up. So, I can't really go into Safe Mode. I tried to get in blindly, but didn't have much luck. The graphics-card isn't new, but the it works when in windows.

Comment: The diagnostic menu you use to get into safe mode should start with a very conservative screen resolution and refresh rate. You should be able to [bash away at F8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode) until you get the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar before - in the fact I made a change to the card and then it appeared to not work at all (although mine wasn't due to refresh rate). Oddly, taking the battery out of the motherboard for 2 minutes and then putting it back in (when the PC is off) did it.

I also had the luxury of a second VGA (built in) which I could have used.

Comment: Yeah, this saved my ass. After I did that, I could see the booting and could easily select Safe Mode. So thanks a lot man.

Comment: Glad it worked for you